# windows command line function findstr produce no output

Tags: windows, command-line

I am trying to extract a string line from a log file on a windows machine, using commandline.
I tried the following command:

**findstr string file.log** but the windows command line prints nothing.

i also tried to redirect output to file using this following command:

**findstr string file.log > anotherfile**, but nothing is written to the file.

i know that there is a match because **errorlevel** is 0. why there is no output ? and how do i retrieve it?

Comment: What do you mean "errorlevel is 0"? why does it prove that file.log is not empty? did you try to open the file and make sure the string you are looking for is really there?

Comment: FYI this is off-topic here, and should be on [su]. Note that the [tag:windows] tag description also points this out: "GENERAL WINDOWS SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com"

Comment: to my understanding errorlevel is a variable that holds last command status. the file was not empty but his encoding was unicode instead of ansi or utf-8 and that is why the function findstr yield nothing. thank you for the help!